# How to get total amount from foreach lop in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get total amount from foreach lop data in the controller, for example, code bellow.

```php
    $set = settings::findOrFail(1);
    $api = new \Binance\API("$set->api_key","$set->scrt_key");
    $api->useServerTime();

    $forusdvaluetotal = coins::whereuser_id(Auth::user()->id)->get();

    foreach($forusdvaluetotal as $coins){
        $getsymbol = $coins->symbol.'USDT';
        $getprice = $api->price("$getsymbol");
        $valueinusd = $coins->balance*$getprice;
        $total = $valueinusd;    
    }

    $gettotal = $total->sum();
```

like "coins A" price is $50 per coin and balance 2, "coins B" price is $50 per coin and balance 5, "coins C" price is $50 per coin and balance 1. So I want to get total amount in USD by balance like ('coins A' $50*2 = $100 + 'coins B' $50*5 = $250 + 'coins A' $50*1 = $50) = $400

Please help me how to solve that in laravel controller.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions are not meant to be **moving targets**. Whenever your question edits significantly invalidate the already given answers, it's best to create a completely new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($forusdvaluetotal as $coins){
    $getprice = $coins['market_price'];
    $valueinusd = $coins['balance']*$getprice;
    $total += $valueinusd;    
}

return $total;
```

Comment: Sorry for some mistakes in my questions. I am already updating it please see again.

Answer (score 0):

One elegant option would be to make use of Laravel's support collection method [`reduce()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reduce).

> The `reduce` method reduces the collection to a single value, passing
> the result of each iteration into the subsequent iteration:
>
> The value for `$carry` on the first iteration is `null`; however, you
> may specify its initial value by passing a second argument to
> `reduce`:

```php
$collection = coins::whereuser_id(Auth::user()->id)->get();

$total = $collection->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + (floatval($item->balance) * floatval($item->market_price));
}, 0);
```

### Addendum

Alternatively, you may make use of Laravel's support collection method [`sum()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum).

> The `sum` method returns the sum of all items in the collection:
>
> In addition, you may pass your own closure to determine which values
> of the collection to sum:

```php
$collection = coins::whereuser_id(Auth::user()->id)->get();

$total = $collection->sum(function ($item) {
    return (floatval($item->balance) * floatval($item->market_price));
});
```

### Edit:

In response to your new question changes, you could solve it this way.

```php
$set = settings::findOrFail(1);
$api = new \Binance\API("$set->api_key","$set->scrt_key");
$api->useServerTime();
$query = coins::whereuser_id(Auth::user()->id);

// Get symbols.
$symbols = (clone $query)->distinct('symbol')->pluck('symbol')->flip()->toArray();

// Fetch prices.
array_walk($symbols, function (&$value, $key) use ($api) {
    $value = $api->price("{$key}USDT");
});

// Get total sum.
$total = $query->get()->reduce(function ($carry, $item) use ($symbols) {
    return $carry + (floatval($item->balance) * floatval($symbols[$item->symbol]));
}, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry for some mistakes in my questions. I am already update it please see again.

Comment: Sorry for some mistakes in my questions. I am already update it please see again.

Comment: Something wrong here, because I can't see where you * use item price. please check again. // Get total sum.
$total = $query->get()->sum(function ($item) use ($symbols) {
    return (floatval($item->balance) * floatval($symbols[$item->symbol]));
});

Comment: @MSURubel , The item price is in `$symbols[$item->symbol]`. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: ok but sum value not showing, it's show "0", but user have a balance in 5 symbol

Comment: for example user have
DOGE - 600
LTC - 0.0345

So I want to show thes balance USDT value in total sum(), price get from $api->price("DOGEUSDT");

Comment: Note that $api->price() working if the symbol written in the bracket like that DOGEUSDT

Comment: @MSURubel , Does `$symbols` have the symbols with their respective prices before `// Get total sum`?

Comment: every symbol price is different, and need to get the price from $api->price("DOGEUSDT")

Comment: @MSURubel , Yes, I'm already aware of that. I meant to request you to inspect that variable for me since I can't do that from my side.

Comment: @MSURubel , Oops, I might have forgotten to clone the `$query` variable on the line below `// Get symbols`. That has been fixed. Try it out, please.

Comment: please fix it for me what you forgott here

Comment: @MSURubel , I did that already. Check my edited answer. `$symbols = (clone $query)->distinct('symbol')->pluck('symbol')->flip()->toArray();`

Comment: ohh, I understand. but still not working. I think here are some missing "// Get total sum."

Comment: floatval($symbols[$item->symbol]) under the // Get total sum.

Comment: @MSURubel , Could you inspect `$symbols` before `// Get total sum`. Does it contain symbols with their respective prices?

Comment: yes, $api->price() get price with a Symbol

Comment: @MSURubel , Okay. Try changing the code below `// Get total sum.` with the new implementation in my edited answer.